# Importing text file contents to database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, text

I'm working with sensor units outfield that spit out data in the form of native text files and have a database created with pre-defined tags. E.G mm, level, voltage. The text file I'm using is pretty unstructured with the data being on the right side of the header separated by semicolon delimiters.

I want to try and import the content into the database where each header matches the tag name and the values are inserted into that tag consecutively. I'm wondering if there's a possible solution or maybe even some tips on how i can achieve this?

Currently i have been working with PHP but haven't gotten to far, is it the best language to use for such a method? Or would javascript be preferred?

Text file is delimited by semicolons:

```
L;MINVi;Min voltage;V;PTi;Processor temperature;C;AVGVi;Average voltage;V;SDB;Network signal dB;dB;WL02;waterlevel 2m;cm;RSSI;Network signal indication;RSSI;OCi;Operating cycle;sec;SCNT;Satellites;;LAT;Latitude;deg;LON;Longitude;deg
S;170427000428;ERR;SERVER_LOGIN;+CME ERROR: Bad or no response from server
S;170427000428;ERR;FTP
S;170427000450;ALARM_SEND_OK
S;170427000510;WDT;GPS
D;170427000510;SCNT;0*T;LAT;0*T;LON;0*T
S;170427000518;ERR;SERVER_LOGIN;+CME ERROR: Bad or no response from server
S;170427000518;ERR;FTP
S;170427000647;ERR;SERVER_LOGIN;+CME ERROR: Bad or no response from server
S;170502171807;POWER_ON;ML-315;V2.7B1
S;170502171807;SYS_START;BHSDemo 5170991
D;170502171817;MINVi;3.66;PTi;25.8;AVGVi;3.71;WL02;2.86*A;OCi;9.95
S;170502171822;WDT;MODEM_INIT
D;170502171823;SDB;0*T;RSSI;0*T
S;170502171823;WDT;Network signal
```

[database table Tag_data Structure](https://puu.sh/xoFDC/75aff77fe5.png)

[image]

Comment: you mean yo want to explode this file text using ; and want to store into database?

Comment: hokletrain  is the file contains only values or  tags also?

Comment: @AshishPatel yes basically but sort the data into where it needs to go.

Comment: @AlivetoDie it only contains header tag names which are assigned to a tag id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/yourtext.txt' INTO TABLE TABLENAME;
```

Comment: Thanks but the text format isn't compatible with load data in file (Inside PhpMyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

Your text will be pretty hard to explode every value with it's parameter because every single word end with `;` so, first try to make your text file like `parameter:value;` or `parameter=value;` or `parameter_value;` then you can read the content of this file with this php function `$content = file_get_contents("path/text_file_name.txt");` now the value of `$content` variable is equal to the entire text of your file hence, you can split this variable into an array  with `$splittedcontent = explode(";" , $content);` every `parameter:value` is a parameter in this array like `$splittedcontent[0] = parameter0:value0`, `$splittedcontent[1] = parameter1:value1` and so on, now you can use `for` loop throw this array and make what your need in you database..
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Cheers for the comment mate. I will change the delimiter to parameter : value ;   , after i have done that how can i go about putting it in the corresponding tags? I understand the changing of the delimiter and chucking it all into an array but not sure about how I'm gonna import it into the table.

Comment: Could you please explain your DataBase structure in plain english or the steps you need to to in points or more details.

Comment: okay so basically the user tags are defined in the front end of the application. Which will house the same values as the text file headers e.g tag name mm and inside the text value there's mm;15. So 15 will be inserted into that tag.

Comment: You have two table or one table?

Comment: Excuse me, are these parameters already in the table and doesn't ?  and you just need to know what is the id of the parameter and put this id in `tag_data` with his value from your text file?.

Comment: Ok, after splitting your text file now each parameter of `$splittedcontent` array represent `target:data`  hence, we just need to split each parameter in this array again then go throw `for` loop as following but  i will skip DB connection

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<count($splittedcontent); $i++){ $tag = explode(":", $splittedcontent[$i]); $query = "SELECT id FROM whatever_your_tag_table_name WHERE  \"tag_name = $tag[0]\""; //type here_the_execution_of_your_query_according_to_your_php_version_on_your_tag_meta_table; $query = "INSERT INTO  tag_data  (tag_id,Date,Time,flag,value) VALUES ("put here your variable you use to execute the pervious $query\", \"put here your date\", \"put here your time\", \"put here your flag\", \"$tag[1]\")"; //type here_the_execution_of_your_query_according_to_your_php_version_on_your_tag_data_table;}`

Comment: the use of back slashes is to skip `"`  to avoid syntax error

Comment: I don't handle the error of data base respond but you should. You should now get the main idea

Comment: Thanks for the help Mohamed. I'm thinking its almost easier just inserting all the data into one table uniquely defined by a unit_id? Couldn't i just insert the value into the table where the header is equal to the field name?

Comment: You are welcom we are here to help each other.. but it is a bad idea to set all your data in one table, you will have a reduntant data you should read about database normlization then think again about that, really you shouldn't do that

Comment: Yea i wen't over it after you said that. I'm going to have to just go with the insertion of tags individually. $splittedcontent will just be the paired key => value data right ? E.g D;17400000 . And with the select statement tag_name[0] , will only retrieve the first name in the array? Do i need to incorporate this over and over ? It's hard putting arrays with this text file because data and names will vary inside of it.